# Make a script to download file and a cron job for it through ssh

Tags: linux, cron, wget

I'm trying to create a script to download a file daily with the older version overwritten.

I'm pretty sure I need a cron job, and a shell script with a wget line in it, but that is as far as I know.  Also, I need to do all of this through ssh, unless there's another way I'm not aware of.

If I do it through SSH, what commands do I need to use through the various steps in the process? What will the cron and the shell files look like? If there's a better way, please enlighten!

Thanks!
Zeem

Comment: Why would you need SSH to automatically download a file? `wget` already supports SSL. Removing old versions is a job for `rm`. A cron job is created via `crontab -e`. Post what you have so far, and people will answer your remaining questions.

Comment: I meant using SSH to create the cron job.

Comment: @KilianFoth Sometimes one would like to login via SSH to download files, that should not be publicly accessibly. Backup-Files for example. If anyone could download them, that would be a mess :D

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I'm picturing the following:

1. connect to the server via SSH
2. find the location of wget

   > which wget

(on my machine it's /usr/bin/wget)

1. add the following to your /etc/crontab (or cronjobs file) using a text editor, such as pico or vi:

   @daily  /usr/bin/wget http://remote-host.name/path/to/file.txt /local/path/to/file.txt

(If you add this to the /etc/crontab, you'll probably need the additional user parameter, but you can see crontab help for that.)

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Implement password-less ssh authentication between the hosts.
http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

So host A can create/implement an script or cronjob on host B using ssh.

To create a cronjob by using a script, your script create (for example) an textfile at `/etc/cron.d/CronJobName`. It is important, that the content of the file corresponds to the corn format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Examples

(I hope, I understand your question right)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers,  Thankfully it was much simpler.  I was able to add a cron job via cpanel, and the wget line went straight in there.